# how to create localhost_access_log file in tomcat 6

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, tomcat6, tomcat8

In my localhost I am using tomcat 8 which is having `localhost_access_log` file.In this file all the requests along with IPAddress,dateTime,Request type(get/post) along with full URL are captured.
But main server is not using tomcat 8 and they are using tomcat 6.So here there is no localhost_access_log file and hence I could not know what and when requests are made to server.

So is there any way to create localhost_access_log or any other way to know the requests made to server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change yout configuration to:

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
            xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">

        <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
        <!--
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
        -->

        <!-- Access log processes all example.
             Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->

        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"  
               prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt" pattern="common" resolveHosts="false"/>
</Host>
```

[See here](http://www.techstacks.com/howto/configure-access-logging-in-tomcat.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,let me try this

Comment: do you know how to view this file in probe?If yes then I will post a new question and you can answer there

Comment: @SpringLearner Sorry but i do not understood what you mean.

Comment: My server is in remote place so how will I view this file.For this purpose I am use probe.war.But in this probe that file is not displaying

Comment: @SpringLearner Sorry but i have no expearience with it. If I have to take a look in logfiles I use ssh to connect to server.

Comment: for using ssh you need to have admin login credentials and you can not view catalina.out file at run time.I mean when ever you want to see minute changes then also you have to download it but in case of probe it is not.Have a look at probe during free time and you will love it

Comment: @SpringLearner No you do not need admin login. You can use a login with lower previliges. also you can see minut changes by using `tail -f` in a unix environemt.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75277/discussion-between-springlearner-and-jens).